# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/3520/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://leafground.com/select.xhtml");

WebElement dropdown3 = driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt87:auto-complete_input"));

Actions dd = new Actions(driver);
dd.moveToElement(dropdown3).click().perform();
WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"j_idt87:auto-complete_panel\"]/ul/li[4]"));
list.click();
```

When ran above code the same failed. Help in resolving the same.

Comment: are you sure there is such an element?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant error message as text, properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to select the dropdown value as below:
[image]

Try the below code:

```
driver.get("https://leafground.com/select.xhtml");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button)[1]")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[text()='Playwright']"))).click();
```

Comment: Tried the above code and got error as below hence help in resolving the same.                                                                                                   1. WebDriverwait - Cannot instantiate the type WebDriverwait                                                                   2. until - The method until is undefined for the type WebDriverWait.

Comment: Have you imported the `WebDriverWait` package? If not, import it in your class and then try. Following is the import statement. `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;`

Comment: Thanks. Hi now the code worked. But want to know how you gave the xpath as when i take the xpath it comes as below which doesnt work.                                                           //*[@id="j_idt87:auto-complete_input"]. This xpath is taken by inspecting choose the course dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues.

1. The first element with the ID, `j_idt87:auto-complete_input`, is an INPUT and you are clicking it. All this does is put the cursor inside the field. I'm assuming you meant to open the dropdown.
2. You don't have any waits. You for sure need a `WebDriverWait` before the second click but probably would be useful to have one before the first click. If you are going to wait until an element is clickable, use `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()`. Presence is just that the element exists in the DOM, not that it visible or ready to be clicked.

If it were me, I would write a method to handle this for you since I'm assuming you will be using this code more than once.

```
public static void selectCourse(String courseName) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[aria-label='Show Options']"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(MessageFormat.format("//li[text()=''{0}'']", courseName)))).click();
}
```

Then call it from your script as

```
selectCourse("Appium");
```